# How to organize TestClass to show in TestExplorer multiple times, once per each parameter?

Tags: c#, mstest

I have MSTest [TestClass] class with 15 test methods [TestMethod]. Test class tests “local” and “remote” storages. Using Visual Studio22’s TestExplorer I would like to see “LocalStorage” tests and “RemoteStorage” tests separately.

Each instance should have two parameters: StorageType and DefaultFolder, that are set up per storage type

How can I achieve that?

Comment: As i understand it, you have e.g. one TestMethod, testing both local and remote, right?

Comment: Use [`TestCategoryAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a base class with the test methods. Don't mark it as `TestClass`. Then inherit classes marked as `TestClass` that set properties of the base class in their initialize method that control behaviour.

```
// base class with test methods
public class BaseStorageTest
{
    protected string defaultFolder;
    protected bool remoteStorage;

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        if (remoteStorage)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Failing remote");
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
    }
}

// Initialize for local test
[TestClass]
public class LocalStorageTest : BaseStorageTest
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        remoteStorage = false;
        defaultFolder = "....";
    }
}

// Initialize for remote test
[TestClass]
public class RemoteStorageTest : BaseStorageTest
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        remoteStorage = true;
        defaultFolder = "....";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Worked just like you advised me.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @RatzMouze create two test classes but if you decide to stick with one test class using [TestCategory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) can be done with an enum rather than a string as with a string if the category name changes you need to change them all by search and replace.

Using an emum

```
public enum Trait
{
    Local,
    Remote
}
```

Usage

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory(nameof(Trait.Local))]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory(nameof(Trait.Remote))]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {

    }
}
```

[image]
See also [Test Traits](https://dev.to/karenpayneoregon/visual-studio-test-traits-431a)

Answer (score 0):

I first misunderstood the question. This answer deals with grouping multiple methods within the same class. See my other answer for the actual question.

---

You can use the [`TestCategory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute) attribute.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Local")]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Local")]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Remote")]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
    }
}
```

Then in the Test Explorer window, choose "Group by > Traits".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, best practise would be to make 2 TestClasses, one for local and one for remote.

By doing this, you automatically get the results seperately.

You should never have TestMethods testing more than one thing.